# Proof inequality and series using Induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

How can I prove that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} ≤ 2 - \frac {1}{n}
$$

using induction?

I first tried to prove this for $P(1)$, so:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1^2} ≤ 2 - \frac {1}1
$$ 
is proved. I then assume that $P(n)$ is proved.

Now I have to prove the same inequality for $P(n+1)$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k^2} ≤ 2 - \frac {1}{n + 1}
$$

I concentrate on the argument on the left and make some changes:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k^2}
$$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac {1}{n+1}
$$

And since $P(n)$ is proved I can change it like this

$$
2 - \frac {1}n + \frac {1}{n+1}
$$

But I can't prove it, cause in the end I get a wrong inequality.

Someone can please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^{\color{red}{2}}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}$$

Using the inductive hypothesis, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}\le\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+2-\frac 1n$$

Now, what you have to prove is 
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+2-\frac 1n\le 2-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In the final inequality I would delete both the 2 cause they null reach other

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-induction solution but included for reference only.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{k^2}\leq 1+\int_1^n \frac 1{k^2}=1+\left[-\frac 1k\right]_1^n=2-\frac 1n$$

Comment: Good to know. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: And this is so much more concise. +1

Comment: @hypergeometric My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I got that to complete the induction I only had to show
$$1/n>(n+2)/(n+1)^2\Leftarrow n(n+2)<(n+1)^2$$
Which is obvious...